# Charity is prescribed for each descendant of Adam Where Can I Find This Hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Where Can I find this hadith is it authentic?

The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Charity is prescribed for each descendant of Adam every day the sun rises." He was then asked: "From what do we give charity every day?" The Prophet (p.b.u.h.) answered: "The doors of goodness are many...enjoining good, forbidding evil, removing harm from the road, listening to the deaf, leading the blind, guiding one to the object of his need, hurrying with the strength of one's legs to one in sorrow who is asking for help, and supporting the feeble with the strength of one's arms--all of these are charity prescribed for you." He also said: "Your smile for your brother is charity." -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hadith can be found in **Fiqh-us-Sunnah, Volume 3, page 98.** The full version of the hadith is as follows:

> It is related following Abu Zhar that the Messenger of Allah, upon
> whom be peace, said: "Sadaqah is prescribed for each descendant of
> Adam every day the sun rises." It was asked: "O Messenger of Allah,
> upon whom be peace, from what do we give sadaqah every day?"
>
> He said: "The doors of goodness are many--the tasbih [to say
> 'Subhaan-Allah'], the tamhid [to say 'Alhamdu lillah'], the tahlil [to
> say 'La-ilaha-illallah], enjoining good, forbidding evil, removing
> harm from the road, listening to the deaf, leading the blind, guiding
> one to the object of his need, hurrying with the strength of one's
> legs to one in sorrow who is asking for help, and supporting the
> feeble with the strength of one's arms--all of these are sadaqah
> prescribed for you."
>
> This is related by Ibn Hibban in his **Sahih**. **Al-Bukhari** related it in a
> shortened form and added in his report: "Your smile for your brother
> is sadaqah. Your removal of stones, thorns, or bones from the paths of
> people is sadaqah. Your guidance of a person who is lost is sadaqah."
>
> Reference: [Islamicstudies.info](http://www.islamicstudies.info/subjects/fiqh/fiqh_us_sunnah/fus3_48.html)